# for loop broke, but debugger can not find any problems

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

To simplify, the for loop in this code does not work. I am trying to have it countdown until `remTime` reaches 0. A while loop works, but only if it's set to `while True:`

Here is the code:

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

currentHour = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H'))
currentMin = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%M'))
currentSec = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S"))

currentHourToSec = currentHour * 3600
currentMinToSec = currentMin * 60

currentTotalSec = currentHourToSec + currentMinToSec + currentSec
remTime = 86400 - currentTotalSec

x = 86400

for x in range(0):
    print(remTime)
    remTime = remTime - 1
    x = x - 1
    sleep(1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: What are you expecting from `range(0)`?

Comment: What is it that you *think* `for x in range(0):` means?

Comment: Well... I tried changing it to `range(86400)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps instead of randomly changing things, you should really understand what you're doing. Randomly changing things won't accomplish anything beyond frustrating you.

Comment: I'm trying to have `remTime` countdown until it reaches 0.

Comment: Can't you just use your `while True` setup, that you claim works? Why are you trying to use a for loop in the first place?

Comment: It works, but it never stops. I want it to stop when `remTime` reaches 0. After all there is no negative time.

Comment: What about `while remTime > 0:` or just `while remTime:` .

Comment: Alternatively, `while True: ...`, then `if remTime == 0: break`

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll go try that.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: A duplicate of what though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in range(remTime, 0, -1):
    print(x)
    sleep(1)
```

According to the docs, range requires a starting value, stopping value, and step, also known as increment/decrement `range(start, stop, step)`.

Since you want `remTime` to be reduced by one, and you want to visually see it go down via `print`, you can use `range(remTime, 0, -1)` which tells python, I want to start from `remTime`, and I want it to step/decrement down by `-1` until it reaches `0`.

Comment: Although it does work, I think giving OP a bit more explanation as to why would be helpful, as OP seems to be a new programmer.

Comment: Ermm, I dont know if this is gonna sound rude, but first what is OP mean?

Comment: Don't worry, it's not rude. OP just means original poster, basically the person who posted the question

Comment: Actually, I dont really know what to explain tho, as Aidan seems to know what he wants and I merely just simpliy the things that he his doing

Comment: No worries, I added an explanation that will hopefully give OP some insight